# Disable dGPU COMPLETELY

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I am on Kubuntu 18.04.

I am manually throttling CPU at ~1.8Ghz. Undervolted -150mV CPU and cache.

But for some reasons the temps just don't go down. Can it be the dGPU (1050 Ti Max Q) acting out? In the drivers settings I can only choose the proprietary nvidia driver or xserver-xorg-video-nouveau. AFAIK nouveau is just proprietary nvidia driver. Is there any way to use iGPU and turn off the dGPU completely? I tried to install xserver-xorg-video-intel but it says it's already installed but I can't see it in the driver selection window.

I get better temps on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I updated to 18.10 and used PRIME select (which wasn't available in Xorg nvidia control center on 18.04) and it is silent as a mouse.